# Making a Object.prototype function causes MongoDB Driver error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prototype

I like to use prototype functions because I prefer doing `({my: "object}).do_stuff()` compared to `do_stuff({my: "object})`. I am using MongoDB to connect to my database but it returns this trace warning error everytime I run my program.

Here is my code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const mongoURL = `mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.mongodb.net/xxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
const client = new MongoClient(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

Object.prototype.do_stuff = function() {
    console.log("do stuff")
}


client.connect(() => {
    console.log('connected');
})
```

I don't even need to call the `do_stuff()` function for the trace warning to occur. This does stop if I use a generic function but does anyone know how I can fix this error. If it's not fixable then no problem, the constant message is getting annoying

Here is the error

```
(node:9404) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: the options [do_stuff] is not supported
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I have tried running `node --trace-warnings` but nothing happens.

Edit:
The problem is that I use the `Object.prototype` function, so everytime a new object is created, the function `do_stuff` is added onto it automatically.
The options when you create a new MongoClient is an object so the `do_stuff` function is added onto it and the constructor cannot find the option `do_stuff` so it returns an error.

Comment: You can try adding a hasOwnProperty check to the driver where it produces this warning and sending that as a PR.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?